# AWS ECS keep spawning new tasks even though the CMD should wait

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

It is as if the CMD has no effect.

In my ECS task definition, I have defined the command as seen in the below screenshot

[image]

The python process is supposed to be a 'blocking process' - it supposes to wait on data in a SQS queue.

However from the cloud watch log, it seems like the task gets spawned continuously 
[image]

In effect it is like executing this

```
 docker run -t simplequeue python /docverter/app/src/main.py
```

The container is started and then terminated right away.

I have defined the ENTRYPOINT in my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y git python python-pip cron ntp

ENV APP_HOME /docverter

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
COPY . ${APP_HOME}

#
# Log configuration

RUN mkdir -p /root/.aws
RUN mkdir -p /var/awslogs/state
COPY ./credentials /root/.aws/credentials
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
RUN python awslogs-agent-setup.py --non-interactive -c ${APP_HOME}/aws-log.cfg --region ap-southeast-2

# Entry point
# To ensure some background services are started when the container is started
ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

And the docker-entrypoint is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

service awslogs start
service ntp start
```

I want to know how I can make the docker container to execute the Command in the task definition

**EDIT** as per Andrey's answer, I have modified the entrypoint script but it does not solve the issue. I added an extra `echo "$@"` for debug and it prints blank.

```
docker build -t broken .
docker run -it broken python    # export to have python started
```

The test code can be cloned from here: `git clone -b broken-entry-point-and-cmd https://github.com/kongakong/aws-ecs`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following at the end of your ENTRYPOINT script

```
exec "$@"
```

Because you are using both, ENTRYPOINT and CMD, CMD values are passed to the ENTRYPOINT  as arguments.

So you need to tell your bash script to launch that python command.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255814/what-purpose-does-using-exec-in-docker-entrypoint-scripts-serve?rq=1

https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/

Comment: Sorry, somehow it does not fix the issue. I have updated the question and make the code accessible via github.